# How to process 300k records from DB : Mule ESB

Tags: database, mule, mule-component

I want to process 300k records from sybase DB running on a remote system.
Currently we are using Batch processing to pull the data from DB.
We also define Batch Block Size: 1000. But we are not able to get records from the db. Please help us.

Comment: please provide some code and test data.

Comment: Please be more specific about your question. "we are not able to get record from the db" why is that? explain please.

Answer (score 0):

You don’t need batch just to pull the data. Batch process would have input, process records and on complete section.  Your database connector should be there in the input area that will fetch all the records and process records will map one record in the output area. 
It looks like there are connection issue in the DB connector. Is the test connection working? Try to use a separate flow and fetch the count and see if you are able to get that.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for process in chuck of 1000 ?

1.Use Poll Scope with Database Connector 
2.Enable Watermark 
3.Go for Sector option.
4.Use Processing Strategy as Synchronous.